# sched_yield for threaded program in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to get 3 threads to print words starting with VOWEL, CONSONANTS and OTHER. Here is my program:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int i,j,n_thread;

pthread_t threads[3];

digit=0;vowels=0;consonants=0,pos=1;


pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL,check_Vower(argc,argv),NULL);
pthread_create(&threads[1],NULL,check_Consonant(argc, argv),NULL);
pthread_create(&threads[2],NULL,check_Other(argc, argv),NULL);


pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);
pthread_join(threads[2],NULL);

printf("\nVowels = %d",vowels);
printf("\nConsonants = %d",consonants);
printf("\nDigits = %d",digit);
return 0;    
}

void *check_Vower(int argc, char** argv)
{

char first;
printf("Thread Vower\n");
int i;

//while(argv[pos] != NULL)
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    printf("arg pos %s\n", argv[pos]);
    first = argv[pos][0];
    //if(isalpha(first)){
        if( (toupper(first)=='A') || (toupper(first)=='E') ||     (toupper(first)=='I') || (toupper(first)=='O') || (toupper(first)=='U'))
        {
            //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            printf("VOWEL: %s\n", argv[pos]);
            vowels++;
            pos++;
            // sched_yield();
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
        }
    //} 

    sched_yield();  
    printf("dkm\n");
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *check_Consonant(int argc, char** argv)
{
printf("Thread consonants\n");
char first;
int i;

//while(argv[pos] != NULL)
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    first = argv[pos][0];

    //if(isalpha(first)){
        if( (toupper(first) !='A') && (toupper(first)!='E') && (toupper(first)!='I') && (toupper(first)=='O') && (toupper(first)!='U'))
        {
            //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            printf("VOWEL: %s\n", argv[pos]);
            vowels++;
            pos++;
            //sched_yield();
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
        }
    //}

    else
        sched_yield();
    printf("sche_yield fails \n");
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *check_Other(int argc, char** argv)
{
printf("Thread Other\n");
int temp;
char first;
temp=toupper(first)-65;

int i;

//while(argv[pos] != NULL)
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    first = argv[pos][0];

    if(!isalpha(first))
    {
        if(temp>-17 && temp<-7) 
        {
            //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            printf("OTHER: %s\n", argv[pos]);
            digit++;
            pos++;
            //sched_yield();
            //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
        } 
    }else
        sched_yield();
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The sched_yield is supposed to yield control to the next thread once it fails to detect a word for that thread but it just keeps reiterating through the for loop and DID NOT relinquish control of CPU and program just stops after its execution.

What did I do wrong in the implementation of thread?

Comment: If your program relies on sched_yield, yield or pthread_yield to work then it is hopeless and will never work at all, ever. The yield calls are an optimization tool and that is all they are.

Comment: Please **format** your code properly, [e.g. according to this guide](http://prohackr112.tk/guide/coding/proper-c-formatting) before posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: To clarify a previous comment; the `sched_yield()` doesn't give the CPU to the "next" thread; it gives the CPU back to the scheduler to decide what to do with it. Under various circumstances (on different operating systems)  the scheduler can decide to give the CPU back to the CPU that just yielded (e.g. maybe because the scheduler knows that thread's data is still in the cache and optimises for "less cache misses"), effectively making `sched_yield()` do nothing (in some circumstances, even when there are other threads waiting to use the CPU).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with yield and everything to do with calling pthread_create with the wrong arguments.

Did you completely ignore all compiler warnings about pointer types?

You are *calling* your thread functions during the pthread_create. Then the thread is trying to execute the return value as a thread function.

Comment: I get zero compilation error regarding with the Pthread_create() function

Comment: @InnoveerHipstirt: Yes I see that too now. I am too used to the defaults including "-Wall -W -pedantic" Add those if you're using GCC

Comment: Anw, do you still think it's because of the pthread_create() method that makes the prog not working as it supposed to?